# How to convert int to String in java

Tags: java, string, int, type-conversion, concatenation

```
public class Apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String base;
        int no1 = 72;
        int no2 = 75;

        base = (String)(no1 + no2);
        System.out.println(base);
    }
}
```

The Above code generates **error** and says that it cannot convert int to String.
Why is this so ?

I am a beginner and from my knowledge I guess that **type-casting** should work here.

Comment: You cannot do a _cast_ here simply because an `int` is not a `String`. They are different types and do not have a type relationship. So you have to _convert_: `String.valueOf(no1) + String.valueOf(no2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `valueOf()` like this:

```
String base = String.valueOf(no1 + no2);
```

Alternatively, If you just want to print the number then you can directly do:

```
System.out.prinltn("Number: " + (no1 + no2));
```

Comment: This works but gives the sum of the two instead of 72 + 75 = 7275. Its Silly but I need it

Comment: That is because you might not be enclosing `no1 + no2` in `()`. You have to do: `(no1 + no2)` and not just `no1 + no2`.

Comment: you can do
      `System.out.println("number:"+n1+"+"+n2);`

Comment: @roony That will give `7275` and not `147`

Comment: it gives 72+75, which is what he said he wants @user2004685

Comment: He want the addition of two numbers i.e. `72` and `75` but getting concatenation i.e. `7275` instead. That is what I understood. Correct me if I'm wrong.